# building sql query to retrieve specific data from database

Tags: sql

Here is the problem I am having.

I have queries I am trying to build for program. Here is the query:

- I need the names of employees who work on exactly one project that is controlled by their department. (It does not matter how many non-departmental projects they work on. To clarify if an employee works on more than 1 project in his own department then I do not want the result. But he can work 1 project in his department as well as other departments. I am only looking for the employees who are working on only 1 project that comes from the department that the project is assigned to.)
- Also I need to show the department name, and the project name and location.
- I want to Show results in ascending alpha order (by last name and then first name) to make it easy to read.

Here are my tables

- `employee` table: fname, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, dno(department number)
- `project` table: projectname, projectnumber, plocation, dnum(department number)
- `works_on` table: ssn, projectnumber, hours_worked
- `department` table: dname, dnumber, managerssn, manager_start_date

Here is what I came up with after working on this for hours:

```
select distinct 
    employee.fname, 
    employee.lname, 
    employee.ssn, 
    employee.dno, 
    project.pnumber, 
    project.dnum
from 
    employee, works_on, project
where 
    employee.dno = project.dnum
    and project.pnumber = works_on.pno;
```

Comment: **Absolutely** show us what you have done! don't worry that it isn't working

Comment: Show us what you have

Comment: ^[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select e.fname, e.lname, e.dno, p.projectname
from employees e
inner join projects p on p.projectnumber = e.project --OR HOWEVER THE 2 ARE LINKED
group by e.fname, e.lname, e.dno, p.projectname
having count(p.Projectnumber) = 1 
order by e.lname asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  e.ssn as employee_ssn
  ,e.dno as employee_department_number
  ,wo.projectnumber
  ,p.projectname as project_name
  ,p.dnum as project_department_number
FROM employees e
JOIN works_on wo on wo.ssn = e.ssn
JOIN projects p on p.projectnumber = wo.projectnumber
WHERE e.dno = p.dnum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      e.fname
    , e.lname
FROM works_on w
      INNER JOIN employee e
                  ON w.ssn = e.ssn
      INNER JOIN project
                  ON w.projectnumber = p.projectnumber
                        AND e.dno = p.dnum
GROUP BY
      e.fname
    , e.lname
HAVING COUNT(w.projectnumber) = 1
```

"on exactly one project that is controlled by their department"

- exactly one project can be determined by HAVING
  COUNT(w.projectnumber) = 1
- controlled by **their** department is the join condition e.dno to p.dnum

Comment: hey thanks alot everyone for all your help. Hey how do you guys know all this stuff? Is there a book I can read or tutorial that I can practice on to learn this stuff? these look like really complex queries. I am just beginning sql. I worked on this for hours and you guys did it in minutes.

Comment: books are still the best way. try this:: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals (Developer Reference) Itzik Ben-Gan (Author)  online there is heaps also try http://sqlzoo.net

Answer (score 0):

So we need to do a join across employee, project, and works_on. We can ignore department, because it's not important. Here's a query that I think would work:

```
select fname, lname, dno, projectname, count(*) as project_count
from employee, project, works_on
where employee.ssn = works_on.ssn and
      works_on.projectnumber = project.projectnumber 
      project.dnum = employee.dno
having project_count = 1
```

- In the select, we do a count(*) as project_count so we can count how
  many projects they are working on.
- In the where, we're matching
  together the rows for the join.
- Line 3 of the where makes sure we're
  only getting projects controlled by their department.
- The having
  clause is the all-important part that allows us to specify a
  condition using an aggregate function: the count(*) project_count, in
  this case.

Depending on which SQL engine you're using, the HAVING clause might have slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a GROUP BY or not, depends on what you mean by "exactly one project". This should be pretty close:

```
select e.fname, e.lname, p.projectname, p.location, d.dname FROM
employee e
INNER JOIN works_on w
ON e.ssn = w.ssn
INNER JOIN project p
ON w.projectnumber = p.projectnumber
INNER JOIN department d
ON p.dnum = d.dnumber
WHERE e.dno = p.dnum
ORDER BY e.lname, e.fname
```